# variable template "SFINAE" not working

Tags: c++, c++14, cbor

I'm trying to implement the size code for the cbor format with "SFINAE", for lack of a better word. But it doesn't work, as `size_code<3>`, for example, evaluates to `0x1b`. What's wrong?

```
template <::std::size_t N,
  typename = ::std::enable_if_t<N <= 0x17>
>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code = N;

template <::std::size_t N,
  typename = ::std::enable_if_t<(N > 0x17) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint8_t>::max())
  >
>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code = 0x18;

template <::std::size_t N,
  typename = ::std::enable_if_t<
    (N > ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint8_t>::max()) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint16_t>::max())
  >
>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code = 0x19;

template <::std::size_t N,
  typename = ::std::enable_if_t<
    (N > ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint16_t>::max()) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint32_t>::max())
  >
>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code = 0x1a;

template <::std::size_t N,
  typename = ::std::enable_if_t<
    (N > ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint32_t>::max()) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint64_t>::max())
  >
>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code = 0x1b;
```

Comment: It shouldn't evaluate to anything. This code is ill-formed for multiply redefining `size_code`.

Comment: You would probably be better off writing a `constexpr` function for this.

Comment: @T.C. gcc oddity, but clang recognizes this.

Comment: I know about constexpr functions and the struct with static constexpr member workaround, but I'd really like to avoid that, if possible

Comment: @TartanLlama I've undeleted. You can post your answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot redefine variable templates like that, so your code shouldn't work.

This would be much simpler with a `constexpr` function, something like this:

```
template <typename T> constexpr T t_max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); 

constexpr std::uint8_t size_code (std::size_t n) { 
    if (n <= 0x17) return n; 
    if (n <= t_max<std::uint8_t>) return 0x18; 
    if (n <= t_max<std::uint16_t>) return 0x19; 
    if (n <= t_max<std::uint32_t>) return 0x1a; 
    if (n <= t_max<std::uint64_t>) return 0x1b; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
template <::std::size_t N, typename = void>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code{};

template <::std::size_t N>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code<N, ::std::enable_if_t<N <= 0x17> > = N;

template <::std::size_t N>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code<N,
  ::std::enable_if_t<(N > 0x17) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint8_t>::max())
  >
> = 0x18;

template <::std::size_t N>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code<N,
  ::std::enable_if_t<
    (N > ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint8_t>::max()) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint16_t>::max())
  >
> = 0x19;

template <::std::size_t N>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code<N,
  ::std::enable_if_t<
    (N > ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint16_t>::max()) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint32_t>::max())
  >
> = 0x1a;

template <::std::size_t N>
constexpr ::std::uint8_t const size_code<N,
  ::std::enable_if_t<
    (N > ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint32_t>::max()) &&
    (N <= ::std::numeric_limits<::std::uint64_t>::max())
  >
> = 0x1b;
```